# Proof of Inequality involving exponentials

Tags: calculus, inequality

I would to be able to show that 
$$ \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+x}\Bigr)-1 \gt \frac{1-\exp(-y/x)}{y}~~~\text{for}~~~1\le y \le x $$

My Attempt:

I start by fixing $x$ and letting $$ f(y) = \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+x}\Bigr)-1 -\frac{1-\exp(-y/x)}{y} $$ 
and then consider $$f'(y) = \frac{y^2 - \exp(-y/x)-\frac{y}{x}\exp(-y/x)}{y^2}. $$
My goal then is to show that $f'(y) \gt 0$. Well, the denominator is always positive, so I examine the numerator. So I consider (with $x$ fixed) $$g(y) = y^2 - \exp(-y/x)-\frac{y}{x}\exp(-y/x)$$ and compute 
$$ g'(y) = y\left( 2 + \frac{\exp(-y/x)}{x^2}\right) \gt 0~~~,y\gt 1$$ This tells me that $g(y)$ is increasing and hence $g(y) \gt g(1) = 1 - \frac{\exp(-1/x)}{x} - \exp(-1/x)$. This where I get stuck because I'm thinking I should get $g(1) =0$.

I would appreciate help in completing the problem. I would also appreciate ways of proving this result.

Comment: $g(1) > 0$ is even better! And it is true.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for your comment. I don't know how to make use of it though.

Comment: I provided a clearer proof in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x$, let $g(y) = \dfrac{1}{y}\left(1 - \exp\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)\right), 1 \leq y \leq x.$
Then 
$$g'(y) = -\frac{1}{y^2}\exp\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)\left[\exp\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) - 1 - \frac{y}{x} \right] < 0,$$
hence $g(y)$ is strictly decreasing on $[1, x]$, thus $g(y) \leq g(1) = 1 - \exp(-1/x)$. Therefore in order to show the inequality, it is sufficient to show that
$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{1 + x}\right) - 1 > 1 - \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right).$$
Or equivalently,
$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{1 + x}\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right) > 2.$$
which follows from that 
$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{1 + x}\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
is strictly decreasing on $[1, +\infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\exp\left(\frac{1}{1 + x}\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) = 2$.